# How to Update android studio flamingo to hedgehog?

Tags: android-studio

I tried doing it in the update section but it shows the following and there is no option to update it to canary. what can i do[No option to update to canary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJkcH.png)

I have tried searching various section of android studio but didn't found such feature to update it to canary especially to hedgehog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download this version manually from below link
Download -> https://developer.android.com/studio/preview